# MSI is Adding Duplicate entries in ARP during a major upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, wix3.11

I have been creating the msi for the next release of our application.

**current version :**

ProductCode : OldProductCode-GUID

ProductVersion : 3.0.0

PackageCode : OldPackageCode-GUID

UpgradeCode : UpgradeCode-GUID

**New version:**

ProductCode : New-GUID

ProductVersion : 3.1.0

PackageCode : New-GUID

UpgradeCode : Same-GUID as the previous version

The msi is configured to install in PerMachine context

The problem I am facing is ,

The Major Upgrade is happening successfully many Windows 10 laptops, But , in some Laptops running windows 10, the Major Upgrade is not happening and the msi is installing another copy of the Applciation. I can see Both versions installed under ARP.

The Install string I am using is

***msiexec /i "MYMSI.msi" /q /norestart /L*V "C:\Windows\Temp\MyLog3-1-0.log"***

Why is the major upgrade not happening is some windows 10 Laptops ? Am i missing something here . Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Please see this list of common causes of major upgrade failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991527/129130). I would check the installation context first - in other words if the product is installed per-machine or per-user (if the product can be installed per-user).

Comment: I forgot to add a script for you: [Find Installed MSI packages](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs). Put it on the desktop on a problem-machine, double click to run, then read the dialog that shows up and press OK - finally wait quite some time before you get a "export complete" message box. Then open "msiinfo.html" by double clicking it - check the last column called "Scope".

Comment: Thank you @SteinÅsmul for the suggestion.  I ran the MsiHtmlReport-Mini.vbs  on the system as you suggested and found both the versions in PerMachine  context.

Comment: Actually the msi was installed to the machines by the SCCM team .  They tried to cleanup the registry on the Problem-machines and tried to re-run the Upgrade . This time , the Upgrade happened without any issues.    The issue is not present now.  I think my Wix configuration is correct. 

Thanks for your support again :-)

Comment: OK, could you please show your SCCM team or packaging team [the list of common major upgrade failure issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991527/129130) and perhaps ask them to comment on any additional issues that they have for inclusion in the list?