# Why does my WiX installer show two entries in Control Panel

Tags: wix

I have created an msi installer using the WiX setup project, and I also have a Bootstrapper project where I have all the other pre requisites for the installation of the msi installer.
When I install the installer, my control panel shows two entries of the same. How do I fix this?

Comment: This usually means that your major upgrade has failed (provided you have set up a major upgrade at all). [Please read this answer on causes of failed major upgrades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989906/wix-does-not-uninstall-older-version/56991527#56991527). It is also possible that you have installed two versions during active development and need to clean them out manually. You can try to [get a list of products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup) and uninstall them both.

Comment: I have gone through the other answers you shared, but I am still stuck with the same issue. Also, I have not set up any upgrades in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the "visible" attribute for my MsiPackage element was set to yes instead of no, which is why I had tow entries in my control panel.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer for others who face the same issue.